# PreferenceFragment changing ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen, preferencefragment

I have an app that has a navigation drawer throughout the app. I've just added a Preferences Activity with a nested PreferenceScreen.

All works well on the main screen, but when I click into the nested screen, the ActionBar defaults to the Android back button, completely removing the context/overflow menu as well the navigation drawer. I'm sure it has something to do with the fragments being replaced, but all my efforts to fix it have done nothing.

How can I have the PreferenceFragment maintain my normal action bar?

Thanks